# How to keep android applications always be login state when application get force update from play store?

Tags: java, android

Right now I am trying to create an Android application. What I want, I logged in that application on my mobile, it should always be logged in whenever I get update from play store that application. How can i create this in **SharedPreference** and also in **RealmDB**.

**Any suggestion will be helpful for me.**

**Thank you**

Comment: Hi Mohammad. This is a very wide and open ended question that can have many many different implementations, and each implementation can be complicated to explain in a single answer.
You may want to narrow down if you want to save things in SharedPreferences, or if you want to save them in RealmDB (or SQLite). From there, maybe look for tutorials on how login information should be stored (often with tokens, and not plain username/password), and ask questions based on what you have tried and what failed with your implementation.

Comment: I am not implement yet. I see tutorials but i want to know if i store data in SharedPreferences is it saved when i update my application or anything i should change in AndroidManifest or Gradle file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create Preferences.java (helper):

```
package ru.str.proglot.visitor.helpers;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class Preferences {


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T getValue(Context context, String key, T defaultValue) {
        SharedPreferences sPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        T resultValue = null;

        if (defaultValue instanceof Boolean)
            resultValue = (T) Boolean.valueOf(sPref.getBoolean(key, (Boolean) defaultValue));
        else if (defaultValue instanceof Float)
            resultValue = (T) Float.valueOf(sPref.getFloat(key, (Float) defaultValue));
        else if (defaultValue instanceof Integer)
            resultValue = (T) Integer.valueOf(sPref.getInt(key, (Integer) defaultValue));
        else if (defaultValue instanceof Long)
            resultValue = (T) Long.valueOf(sPref.getLong(key, (Long) defaultValue));
        else if (defaultValue instanceof String)
            resultValue = (T) sPref.getString(key, (String) defaultValue);

        return resultValue;
    }

    public static <T> void setValue(Context context, String key, T value) {
        SharedPreferences sPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sPref.edit();

        if (value instanceof Boolean)
            editor.putBoolean(key, (Boolean) value);
        else if (value instanceof Float)
            editor.putFloat(key, (Float) value);
        else if (value instanceof Integer)
            editor.putInt(key, (Integer) value);
        else if (value instanceof Long)
            editor.putLong(key, (Long) value);
        else if (value instanceof String)
            editor.putString(key, (String) value);

        editor.apply();
    }

    public static void remove(Context context, String key) {
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().remove(key).apply();
    }

    public static void clear(Context context ) {
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().clear().apply();
    }



}
```

Next, save info from anywhere:

```
Preferences.setValue(this, "name", "Ivan");
```

And get value:

```
Preferences.getValue(this, "name", "");
```